# Android ProgressBar in my View

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to place a loading spinner into my canvas. In the constructor:

```
this.progressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, Resource.Attribute.progressBarStyle);
```

And in the `OnDraw`:

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    base.OnDraw(canvas);

    // other code to draw other stuff...

    this.progressBar.Draw(canvas);
}
```

It is not appearing. Am I missing something?
I checked the `Width` property and it is 0 while debugging, but I still don't know how to fix it.

My class extends `View`

Comment: If you want to place inherit view, you need to extent ViewGroup or any 'layout' class, not simple View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend you class from ViewGroup or any layout (e.g. FrameLayout), then during initialization you need to call addView methods with your progress bar.

If you extending simple ViewGroup that additionally you need to override onMeasure and onLayout methods for providing computing size of progress widget and placing it on view group accordingly.

[Here is a tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom/) for Xamarin users for with more info.

Comment: I changed it to a `RelativeLayout` and added the view but it's still not working: `this.progressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, Resource.Attribute.progressBarStyle);
            this.AddView(this.progressBar);`. It works when I try to add something else like a TextView

Comment: Did you provided layout params?

Comment: yes like this: `progressBar.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100);` and still nothing. But if I set the background to red I get a red square..

Comment: I fixed it by removing the last 2 parameters in the constructor: `progressBar = new ProgressBar(context)`